# Application that manages the students in a faculty

Tags: java

As the title says, i have to make an application that manages the students. Students are organized in groups. The students have to be written from a text file, each one being taken in groups. If i have a limit of 30 students per group, then for 60 students i will have 2 groups. Being new to Java, i don't really know how to increase the group id after 30 students are reached, or, i don't know a way. I was thinking about Map or something like this. This is what i made so far. Any suggestions?

Student class:

```
public class Student {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private String CNP;
private int grade;
private boolean leader;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String CNP, int grade, boolean leader) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.CNP = CNP;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.leader = leader;
}
```

}

Faculty class:

```
public class Faculty {
private int groupIterator;
private List<Student> list;

public Faculty() throws Exception {
    list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("---"));

    String line;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    String CNP;
    int grade;
    boolean leader;

    while(fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        firstName = line;
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        lastName = line;
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        age = Integer.parseInt(line);  
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        CNP = line;
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        grade = Integer.parseInt(line); 
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        leader = Boolean.parseBoolean(line);  
        list.add(new Student(firstName,lastName,age,CNP,grade,leader));
    }

    fileIn.close();
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything here where you've tried to incorporate the idea of groups.  "private int groupIterator" is the only mention I see of groups.  Have you tried at all to add the notion of groups?  What is the end result that you want?   Right now you'll end up with a list of Student objects.  What more do you want exactly?

Comment: If you just want to add a 'group' field to each Person object, you could look at the size of the list just before you add each Person.  You could do (len(list) / 30) to give yourself a group ID that would be '0' for the first 30 students added, then '1' for the next 30.  Is that all you want/need?  Just add a 'group' parameter to your Person constructor and pass in **len(list)/30**.

Comment: Sorry for poor explanation, i did not know how to formulate this. I just have a Faculty class and that Faculty class contains a list of groups (Students are organized in groups). I just want to put every student written from a text, in that list from the Faculty. My problem is: if  i have in that text file 45 student for example, 30 students will be in a group in that faculty, and the other 15 will be in the second group and so on, for 90 students i will have 3 groups. This is all i need to know, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands right now your code is confusing as to the role that `Faculty` plays.  It seems it represents a teacher and their students for a class.  However, it also has the code necessary to parse incoming students.  This would be a poor design choice.

The best OOP way to do this would be to have a `Registrar` class.  This would basically represent the school entity that would place students with a teacher.  It would parse your files placing students into the `Faculty` class.

The `Faculty` class should have a method `isClassFull` (`students.size >= 30`) that `Registrar` will use to determine if a new student needs a new `Faculty` because the prior `Faculty` is full.  The registrar would then create a new Faculty and repeat the process.

The end result will be a `Registrar` with a list of `Faculty`, which has a list of up to 30 `Student`.

Since this seems to be a student exercise I'll leave the implementation to you, but hopefully that clears up how to represent this concept in code.

Answer (score 0):

Student:

```
public class Student {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private String CNP;
private int grade;
private boolean leader;
private int group;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String CNP, int grade, boolean leader, int group) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.CNP = CNP;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.leader = leader;
    this.group = group;
}
```

Faculty:

```
public class Faculty {
private int groupIterator;
private List<Student> list;

public Faculty() throws Exception {
    list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("---"));

    String line;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    String CNP;
    int grade;
    boolean leader;

    while(fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        firstName = line;
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        lastName = line;
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        age = Integer.parseInt(line);  
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        CNP = line;
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        grade = Integer.parseInt(line); 
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        leader = Boolean.parseBoolean(line);  
        // Here's the key bit - we now pass in the group id based on the list size
        list.add(new Student(firstName,lastName,age,CNP,grade,leader,len(list)/30));
    }

    fileIn.close();
}
```